# lean interactive protoype platform with analytics AND video capability

Tags: mockups, framerjs

We're looking at creating an interactive prototype for an app with the following specs:

1) embedded videos

2) very good analytics

3) multiple screens

We're looking to optimize for time and I've been considering the following options with the following cons:

1) Framerjs - Con: no good or easy analytics

2) Invision - Con: no way to embed videos (there's the option of embedding a link to a hosted video, but that would take away from the user experience that's critical for our interactive model

2) Xcode Storyboard - Con: first, we haven't settled on building this as a native app, and concerned with complexity (time consumption) particulary with the test flight deployment process.

I'm interested to hear you alls thoughts on this.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to try the new Facebook Origami Studio (Quartz Composer). Video embedding works fine. Quickly put together a prototype, run it on your iPhone or iPad, iterate on it, and export code snippets your engineers can use. 
https://facebook.github.io/origami/